# AutoMySQLBackup: Create a single file for each database

Tags: centos, backup, database-backup

I'm backupping my databases with [automysqlbackup](https://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/).

This works fine - but unfortunately I do not get a single file for each database but a cumulative file called

`daily_all-databases_2016-04-15_12h01m_Friday.sql.gz`

```
.
├── daily
│   └── daily_all-databases_2016-04-15_12h01m_Friday.sql.gz
├── latest
├── monthly
├── tmp
└── weekly
```

I would like to get a single archive for each database.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `SEPDIR` config parameter. It will create separate directories for each database, with an own file inside of it.

From the [Ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/automysqlbackup.8.html) (but should work on CentOS just the same):

> SEPDIR=yes
>   Separate backup directory and file for each DB? (yes or no)

Alternatively, it's very simple to write up a bash script yourself that does this. Something like this should do:

```
mysql -u user -p pass -B -e "SHOW DATABASES"|sed 1d|while read db
do
    mysqldump -u user -p pass $db|gzip>"/home/db_backup/$db.sql.gz"
    if [[ $? != 0 ]];then
        echo "Backup of database $db FAILED!"
    fi
done
```

Obviously replace `user` and `pass` with their respective values.

Comment: Didn't see the `sepdir` parameter on my install, but doing this manually with just `mysqldump` would ignore the advantage of `automysqlbackup` in the form of incremental backups with automatic rename and deletion of old files.

Comment: @Sven True, it's just an illustration of very simple dumping script. It's just an alternative in case the sepdir parameter doesn't offer what OP is looking for.